# Python3 | Как реализовать парсер

Tags: python, python-3.x

Реализовал парсер, код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen('http://google.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))

    html_next = urllib.request.urlopen(str(link.get('href'))).read()
    soup_next = BeautifulSoup(html_next, "html.parser")
    for link_next in soup_next.find_all('a'):
        print(link_next.get('href'))
```

Все отлично выводиться, только вот *более 50%* это неполные url адреса по типу **/advanced_image_search?hl=uk&authuser=0** или **/feed/history** .

И они исходят из разных источников, /advanced_image_search?hl=uk&authuser=0 = http://google.com/advanced_image_search?hl=uk&authuser=0, /feed/history не будет приравниваться к google.com,так как будет возникать ошибка 404 url не найден, и так со всеми неполными url адресами. Я понятия не имею как решить эту столь обширную проблему.

Обходить данные url адреса не вариант, ибо по ним нужно будет проходить и собирать данные, картинки, скрипты и т.д.

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: Используйте только пробелы для отступов при форматировании исходного кода.

Comment: @mkkik спасибо) теперь заработало, вывелось около 1000 url адресов. Но более 50% это неполные url адреса, как мне заменить их на полные? :D /feed/history, /feed/trending или даже заменять не надо, а просто скачать эту html страницу, но я её не скачаю, так как будет выбить invalid url

Comment: @you have no pass добавляйте имя домена, с которого получаются неполные url.

Comment: @LexHobbit это я знаю, не все так просто, допустим обычный http://google.com/ не подходит к products/search/ и я попросту не знаю что и куда подставлять.

Comment: заголовок вопроса никакого отношения к проблеме не имеет. Это делает ваш вопрос практически бесполезным для будущих посетителей из гугла. Я же вам явно предлагал заголовок вопроса: [*"Откуда взялась: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation"*](https://goo.gl/YyB251). Глядя на вашу историю: у вас все вопросы чрезмерно обширные ("Работа с сетью", "Сниффер трафика", "Парсинг сайта", "Как реализовать парсер"). Представьте вы из гугла пришли, заинтересовавшись заголовком, а вместо этого получили лекцию о табах и пробелах. Старайтесь более сфокусированные вопросы задавать.