# Python3 | Как пропускать неверные url адреса при парсинге сайта

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Увидел пост - [Python3 | Как реализовать парсер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693564/python3-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80)

Так вот, как мне пропускать неверные/неполные url адреса ? 
Типа "/start/page/uus.html" или "/" и так далее . 
Перехватывать исключения можно, но как переходить к последующим url, не понятно.
Раз уже как я вижу, не кто не сможет решить проблему с подменой неполных url адресов

Comment: Нет никакой "проблемы неполных адресов". Просто дописывайте в их начало адрес сайта, с которого вы их спарсили.

Comment: @Александр как раз есть, более 60% это не основной url адрес типа google.com , а gmail.com большинство из них разные

Comment: Скажите, а вы вообще понимаете, что эти 60% ссылок - не с первой страницы, а с тех страниц, на которые парсер переходил с неё?

Comment: @Александр допустим даже если это так, тогда как я узнаю предыдущий url?

Comment: Да включите уже голову хоть на минуту. Ваш парсер на эти страницы попал, так? Если он на них перешёл, значит их адреса у парсера есть. Теперь просто посмотрите на ваш код, и найдите, в какую переменную они у вас складываются.